# Learning if statements. Would this work?

Tags: c++, if-statement

will this code work? It doesn't seem to have any errors but my compiler wont show any results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/* declaration */


int smallest (int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int smallest){
    if (i1 < smallest){
        smallest = i1;
    }
    else if (i2 < smallest) {
        smallest = i2;
    }
    else if (i3 < smallest) {
        smallest = i3;
    }
    else if (i4 < smallest) {
        smallest = i4;
    }
    else if (i5 < smallest){
        smallest = i5;
    }
    else {
        smallest = smallest; 
    }
    return (0);
}
```

I'm trying to do a HW assignment for my into to C++ class and this is one of the questions.

Suppose I have five *int* variables named `i1, i2, i3, i4, and i5`
Convert this pseudo-code to C or C++ code:

```
let smallest = smallest(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5)
```

also on his lecture notes he shows this as a similar example

```
std::string smallest;
std::string largest;
if (s < t) {
    smallest = s;
    largest = t;
}

else if (s > t) {
    smallest = t;
    largest = s;
}

else {
    smallest = t; //change the value that is stored in s
    largest = s; //change the value that is stored in t
}

std::cout << smallest << std::endl;
std::cout << largest << std::endl;
```

Thats why i used the if else statements.

Comment: use `for loop` in this case

Comment: You're modifying a local copy (the parameter `smallest`) and always return the same value.

Comment: What results would you want to see? You don't call the function anywhere...

Comment: You should probably also `return smallest;` instead of `return 0`. Your code right now kinda looks like Visual Basic, but in C++, the return value of the function at the usage site is always given in the `return` statement itself.

Comment: how about adding a `switch` statement in there? ;)

Comment: `smallest = smallest; ` does nothing. It seems to me you don't even want to have `int smallest` as a function parameter; have a local variable instead and initialize it to `i1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are modifying smallest, which is passed in. Don't do that.
2. Create a local variable of type int in your function and use it to track the smallest.
3. Remove the else and just do if. You need to check all of the passed in integers.
4. Save the smallest i to the local variable only. It will get overwritten if one of the other i variables is smaller.

   1. Return the local variable, not 0.
5. Create an int main function and call smallest with all necessary parameters from main.
6. Save the result into a local int in main.
7. Print out the result.

Answer (score 0):

You have no `main()` function in this code- therefore, nothing will happen and the function cannot be called.

As a side note, you are not modifying the variable `smallest` once the function exits. Try returning `smallest` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you pass 4,3,2,1 and the smallest is 5. Then your function (that should return the value `smallest` not `0`) will report that 4 is the smallest. You need to remove the `else` branches and verify each and every value you pass.

Comment: I would appreciate a word on what was wrong this this answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int checkSmallest(int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int smallestAtm = checkSmallest(-8, 4, 3, 7, 8);
    cout << smallestAtm; 
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

int checkSmallest(int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5)
{
    int curSmallest = 0;

    if (i1 < curSmallest)
        curSmallest = i1;
    if (i2 < curSmallest)
        curSmallest = i2;
    if (i3 < curSmallest)
        curSmallest = i3;
    if (i4 < curSmallest)
        curSmallest = i4;
    if (i5 < curSmallest)
        curSmallest = i5;

    return curSmallest;
}
```

Comment: and whats stdafx.h?  also what is _TCHAR?